Asyncio multiprocessing communication with queues - only one coroutine running
I have a manager script that's launching some processes, then using two coroutines (one to monitor, one to gather results). For some reason only one coroutine seems to be run, what am I missing? (I don't work with asyncio)

import multiprocessing as mp
import time 
import asyncio
import logging 

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

class Process(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self, task_queue: mp.Queue, result_queue: mp.Queue):
        super().__init__()
        self.task_queue = task_queue
        self.result_queue = result_queue
        logging.info('Process init')

    def run(self):
        while not self.task_queue.empty():
            try:
                task = self.task_queue.get(timeout=1)
            except mp.Queue.Empty:
                logging.info('Task queue is empty')
                break
            
            time.sleep(1)
            logging.info('Processing task %i (pid %i)', task, self.pid)
            self.result_queue.put(task)
            
        logging.info('Process run')

class Manager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.processes = []
        self.task_queue = mp.Queue()
        self.result_queue = mp.Queue()
        self.keep_running = True

    async def monitor(self):
        while self.keep_running:
            await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
            logging.info('Task queue size: %i', self.task_queue.qsize())
            logging.info('Result queue size: %i', self.result_queue.qsize())
            self.keep_running = any([p.is_alive() for p in self.processes])


    async def consume_results(self):
        while self.keep_running:
            try:
                result = self.result_queue.get()
            except mp.Queue.Empty:
                logging.info('Result queue is empty')
                continue

            logging.info('Got result: %s', result)

    def start(self):
        # Populate the task queue
        for i in range(10):
            self.task_queue.put(i)

        # Start the processes
        for i in range(3):
            p = Process(self.task_queue, self.result_queue)
            p.start()
            self.processes.append(p)

        # Wait for the processes to finish
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.create_task(self.monitor())
        loop.create_task(self.consume_results())

manager = Manager()
manager.start()


expecting to see the monitor queue sizes, however only the consume_results() is run


Just to clarify, what you mean by "don't work with asyncio" is that you aren't familiar with it? And, what you mean by 'monitor queue size' because I don't see such term in code nor it has any comments explaining if it's Manager.task_queue or not.

And, are you sure you tested your MRE? Multiprocessing without wrapping it in if __name__ == '__main__': guard this will totally fail due to how multiprocessing work.

I'm just running it in a notebook for testing - the multiprocessing appears to work correctly but only one asyncio coroutine is being run

That totally doesn't work on non-notebooks.. MP automatically throws error that we did not have if __name__ == '__main__': guard. You probably should've included that you use jupyter notebook in question.

Here I'm assuming that you
monitor queue sizes, and that you didn't mention env you are in, I'm assuming it's latest 3.12.x.

Issues


You Block the asyncio thread by .get() call.

    async def monitor(self):
        while self.keep_running:
            try:
                result = self.result_queue.get()




there's no multiprocessing.Queue.Empty.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\Python312\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "E:...\StackOverflow\78475657\78475657.py", line 20, in run
    except mp.Queue.Empty:
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'Empty'




multiprocess Won't work well without guard, seemingly on either Notebook and requires saving target function as separate file and import it or not.

RuntimeError: 
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.

        To fix this issue, refer to the "Safe importing of main module"
        section in https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html     




you Didn't wait for the process. Your main process finished thus throw KeyboardInterrupt on all child processes to halt the program.

Process Process-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\Python\Python312\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "...\StackOverflow\78475657\78475657.py", line 24, in run
    time.sleep(1)
KeyboardInterrupt
  File "...\Python\Python312\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "...\Python\Python312\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "...\StackOverflow\78475657\78475657.py", line 24, in run
    time.sleep(1)
  File "...\StackOverflow\78475657\78475657.py", line 24, in run
    time.sleep(1)
KeyboardInterrupt
KeyboardInterrupt
Exception ignored in atexit callback: <function _exit_function at 0x000001C044853CE0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\Python\Python312\Lib\multiprocessing\util.py", line 357, in _exit_function
    p.join()
  File "...\Python\Python312\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 149, in join
    res = self._popen.wait(timeout)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "...\Python\Python312\Lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 110, in wait
    res = _winapi.WaitForSingleObject(int(self._handle), msecs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyboardInterrupt: 




you Didn't wait for the loop. Hence every tasks just immediately got cancelled via KeyboardInterrupt.

# Wait for the processes to finish
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(self.monitor())
loop.create_task(self.consume_results())

ERROR:asyncio:Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-1' coro=<Manager.monitor() running at ...\StackOverflow\78475657\78475657.py:39>>
...\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py:709: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Manager.monitor' was never awaited
  self._ready.clear()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
ERROR:asyncio:Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-2' coro=<Manager.consume_results() running at ...\StackOverflow\78475657\78475657.py:46>>
...\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py:709: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Manager.consume_results' was never awaited
  self._ready.clear()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback




asyncio.get_event_loop() Deprecation warning.


Deprecated since version 3.12: Deprecation warning is emitted if there is no current event loop. In some future Python release this will become an error.

...\StackOverflow\78475657\78475657.py:67: DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop
  loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

However, since in notebook is already in Async Context and has loop, it's opposite in there and what you did is correct.



Some check in loop checking if queue is empty is redundant.

        while not self.task_queue.empty():  # < no use due to race condition
            try:
                task = self.task_queue.get(timeout=1)  # actual important check
            except mp.Queue.Empty:
                logging.info('Task queue is empty')
                break



Fixes

Use asyncio.to_thread to push blocking call to thread.

Use queue.Empty


import queue

try:
    ...
except queue.Empty:
    ...



add Process.join or better yet use mp.Pool.

# from https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html
from multiprocessing import Process
import os

def info(title):
    print(title)
    print('module name:', __name__)
    print('parent process:', os.getppid())
    print('process id:', os.getpid())

def f(name):
    info('function f')
    print('hello', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    info('main line')
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()



wait for tasks.

import asyncio


async def some_task():
    print("Start")
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    print("End")


def unrecommended_old_way():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    task_1 = loop.create_task(some_task())
    task_2 = loop.create_task(some_task())

    print("Task spawn done")
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(task_1, task_2))
    print("Tasks all done")


unrecommended_old_way()

Task spawn done
Start
Start
End
End
Tasks all done



or use better, recommended way to do above

import asyncio


async def some_task():
    print("Start")
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    print("End")


async def recommended_way():
    task_1 = asyncio.create_task(some_task())
    task_2 = asyncio.create_task(some_task())

    print("Task spawn done")
    await asyncio.gather(task_1, task_2)
    print("Tasks all done")


asyncio.run(recommended_way())



Use mp.JoinableQueue




Actual fix
Originally I'd not recommend mixing concurrency frameworks, but after knowing notebook is using asyncio by default - I think it kinda makes sense why you was trying it. Sorry for misunderstanding!
Here's what you probably wanted, mixing asyncio and multiprocessing.
other_file.py:
import multiprocessing as mp
import logging
import queue
import time


class WorkerProcess(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self, task_queue: mp.JoinableQueue, result_queue: mp.Queue, timeout_sec=2):
        super().__init__()

        self.task_queue = task_queue
        self.result_queue = result_queue
        self.timeout = timeout_sec

    def run(self):
        logging.info(f"[{self.pid:10}] Started")

        while True:
            try:
                task_id, task = self.task_queue.get(timeout=self.timeout)
            except queue.Empty:
                break

            try:
                logging.info(f"[{self.pid:10}] Processing {task_id}")
                time.sleep(1)
                logging.info(f"[{self.pid:10}] Processing {task_id} done")

                self.result_queue.put(task)
            finally:
                # signal JoinableQueue that task we took is done
                self.task_queue.task_done()

        logging.info(f"[{self.pid:10}] Done")



in other file or notebook:
import multiprocessing as mp
import asyncio
import logging

from other_file import WorkerProcess

logging.root.setLevel(logging.NOTSET)


class Manager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.task_queue = mp.JoinableQueue()
        self.result_queue = mp.Queue()

    async def _monitor(self):
        """Periodically reports queue sizes.
        Automatically cancelled after all processes are killed."""

        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

            logging.info(f"[Manager]   Task queue size: {self.task_queue.qsize()}")
            logging.info(f"[Manager] Result queue size: {self.result_queue.qsize()}")

    async def _process(self):
        """Do whatever you want here for results"""

        while (val := await asyncio.to_thread(self.result_queue.get)) is not None:
            logging.info(f"[Manager] Got result {val}")

    async def start(self):
        """Wait for all tasks to be done"""

        # Populate the task queue
        for task_idx, task in enumerate(range(10)):
            self.task_queue.put((task_idx, task))

        # create loop, monitoring task & result process task
        monitor_task = asyncio.create_task(self._monitor())
        result_proc_task = asyncio.create_task(self._process())

        # Start the processes
        processes = [
            WorkerProcess(self.task_queue, self.result_queue)
            for _ in range(3)
        ]
        for process in processes:
            process.start()

        logging.info("[Manager] Started")

        # wait for all tasks to be done. If so, cancel monitor task and wait for it to end
        await asyncio.to_thread(self.task_queue.join)
        monitor_task.cancel()

        # since .task_done() emit is AFTER putting to result queue,
        # there's no race condition here. Send sentinel to result queue
        # to signal end of process.
        self.result_queue.put(None)

        logging.info("[Manager] Done")


manager = Manager()

# if running normally:
# asyncio.run(manager.start())

# in notebook (already in async context)
await manager.start()


Normal run log:
INFO:root:[   Manager] Started
INFO:root:[     22356] Started
INFO:root:[     22356] Processing 0
INFO:root:[     14468] Started
INFO:root:[     14468] Processing 1
INFO:root:[     21076] Started
INFO:root:[     21076] Processing 2
INFO:root:[   Manager]   Task queue size: 7
INFO:root:[   Manager] Result queue size: 0
INFO:root:[     22356] Processing 0 done
INFO:root:[     14468] Processing 1 done
INFO:root:[     22356] Processing 3
INFO:root:[   Manager] Got result 0
INFO:root:[     14468] Processing 4
INFO:root:[   Manager] Got result 1
INFO:root:[     21076] Processing 2 done
INFO:root:[     21076] Processing 5
INFO:root:[   Manager] Got result 2
INFO:root:[   Manager]   Task queue size: 4
INFO:root:[   Manager] Result queue size: 0
INFO:root:[     22356] Processing 3 done
INFO:root:[     22356] Processing 6
INFO:root:[   Manager] Got result 3
INFO:root:[     14468] Processing 4 done
INFO:root:[     14468] Processing 7
INFO:root:[   Manager] Got result 4
INFO:root:[     21076] Processing 5 done
INFO:root:[     21076] Processing 8
INFO:root:[   Manager] Got result 5
INFO:root:[   Manager]   Task queue size: 1
INFO:root:[   Manager] Result queue size: 0
INFO:root:[     22356] Processing 6 done
INFO:root:[     22356] Processing 9
INFO:root:[   Manager] Got result 6
INFO:root:[     14468] Processing 7 done
INFO:root:[   Manager] Got result 7
INFO:root:[     21076] Processing 8 done
INFO:root:[   Manager] Got result 8
INFO:root:[   Manager]   Task queue size: 0
INFO:root:[   Manager] Result queue size: 0
INFO:root:[     22356] Processing 9 done
INFO:root:[   Manager] Got result 9
INFO:root:[     21076] Done
INFO:root:[     14468] Done
INFO:root:[     22356] Done
INFO:root:[   Manager] Done



Notebook will have no such process logs as each process's outputting it's own stdout stderr files, which isn't a notebook but is console.
Hence output is instead on console (if notebook's running on localhost, not collab)

Terminal:
INFO:root:[     22228] Started
INFO:root:[     22228] Processing 0
INFO:root:[     21712] Started
INFO:root:[     21712] Processing 1
INFO:root:[     20724] Started
INFO:root:[     20724] Processing 2
INFO:root:[     21712] Processing 1 done
INFO:root:[     22228] Processing 0 done
INFO:root:[     21712] Processing 3
INFO:root:[     22228] Processing 4
INFO:root:[     20724] Processing 2 done
INFO:root:[     20724] Processing 5
INFO:root:[     21712] Processing 3 done
INFO:root:[     22228] Processing 4 done
INFO:root:[     21712] Processing 6
INFO:root:[     22228] Processing 7
INFO:root:[     20724] Processing 5 done
INFO:root:[     20724] Processing 8
INFO:root:[     21712] Processing 6 done
INFO:root:[     22228] Processing 7 done
INFO:root:[     21712] Processing 9
INFO:root:[     20724] Processing 8 done
INFO:root:[     21712] Processing 9 done
INFO:root:[     22228] Done
INFO:root:[     20724] Done
INFO:root:[     21712] Done
[I 2024-05-15 16:43:24.204 ServerApp] Saving file at /Untitled1.ipynb


First off, sorry, I wrote this code just for SO to make it clearer but it had the opposite effect by introducing some bugs. The effort was there and I've read several guides on asyncio/mp but sometimes it's easy to get stuck on one approach set in your mind from the beginning. Anyways thanks for the fantastic answer - the last section is very helpful.

I did miss the blocking get


@Alter Ah I see, I was kinda angry misunderstanding you just tossed stripped down actual code without any details looking at UML, sorry on my end too! Didn't thought someone would go as far considerate as to create UML for demo code. Will update cold wordings!


Fixed some unclear parts and added missing fix for blocking calls

